# pyTigerGraph Connector Issue with TigerGraph Cluster on AWS

Tags: python, connector, tigergraph

Like to tap into the community intelligence on this specific issue I encountered when trying to access TigerGraph Cluster on AWS using the Python Connector. It seemed my API worked and I was able to run most functions, except when I tried to run `.gsql()` I started to have issues. BTW, running standalone GSQL client was successful. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Troubleshootings I have tried but failed:

1. Specified a local dir for the gsql_client.jar file using `conn.initGsql(jarLocation="/home/user/gsql_clients/dv-TGv3.1/gsql_client.jar")`.  Unfortunately, `jarLocation` was not an available argument, although it is documented https://pytigergraph.github.io/pyTigerGraph/Gsql/. Is this a known issue with this package?
2. Changed my local gsql_client.jar file to the default directory and rename it to `/home/user/.gsql/gsql_client-3.1.1.jar` following the instruction in https://pytigergraph.github.io/pyTigerGraph/Gsql/
3. Downgraded the Python connector to pyTigherGraphBeta v0.0.9.7

However, neither has resolved the issue for me and I got the same error message as shown below.

Below are my configs and codes and errors.

- Python 3.6
- pyTigerGraph v0.0.9.6.8

```
import pyTigerGraph as tg
conn = tg.TigerGraphConnection(host="http://tigergraph.domain.com",
    restppPort="9000",
    gsPort="80",
    graphname="my_graph",
    username="user",
    password="xxx",
    useCert=False,
    apiToken="xxx",
    gsqlVersion="3.1.1"
)
print(conn.getVertexTypes())
```

> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'y, 'z']

```
print(conn.gsql('''LS''', options=[]))
```

> Connection Failed check your Username/Password [Errno 111] Connection refused
> Couldn't Initialize the client see Above Error

Comment: After upgrading pyTigerGraph to the latest version 0.0.9.6.9, the issue was resolved.  Just to clarify, I still used my own credentials instead of the defaults to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest change to the package was the removal of the Java dependency. This happened in the 0.0.9.6.5 version release. The packages [**pyTigerGraph 0.0.9.6.5**](https://pypi.org/project/pyTigerGraph/#history) - > **pyTigerGraph 0.0.9.6.8** versions are using the [pyTigerDriver package](https://pypi.org/project/pyTigerDriver/)

Could you verify that it's using the latest version and use these default parameters? pyTigerGraph will conduct a few checks to verify the other parameters you passed previously.

It might be an SSL issue...

```
import pyTigerGraph as tg
conn = tg.TigerGraphConnection(host="http://tigergraph.domain.com",
    graphname="my_graph",
    username="user",
    password="xxx",
)
```

**Additional Resources:**

[Complete walkthrough of pyTigerGraph Intro Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2BcC3C-qfX4)

[Link to Colab to follow along](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1fJpcv-q0NLfHj3X1k6Lbwddp8gVVcfES?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the contributors to the package pyTigerGraph , I would like to thank you for the post.
Please note that this part of the doc is obsolete will be deleted asap ( https://pytigergraph.github.io/pyTigerGraph/Gsql/ ) , thanks for raising that issue .
if you're running  v0.0.9.6.8 , then you wouldn't need the jar client.
Please try the following code :
Note that :

- gsPort = "14240" ( by default is 14240 )
- username="user"  ( user by default tigergraph )
- graphname="MyGraph" ( double check the graphname )

```
import pyTigerGraph as tg
conn = tg.TigerGraphConnection(host="http://tigergraph.domain.com",
    gsPort="14240",
    graphname="MyGraph",
    username="tigergraph",
    password="tigergraph",
    gsqlVersion="3.1.1"
)
conn.apiToken = conn.getToken(conn.createSecret())
print(conn.echo())
print(conn.getVertexTypes())
print(conn.gsql("LS")
print(conn.gsql("USE GRAPH MyGraph")
```

you can refer for this colab for full reference :
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1iKtauUoMCPOR7f2ExO70gQOJ_LWwWIp4?usp=sharing

and check out this video by Dan :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oDp1hg9jSLU